# Per module authentication with returnUrl

Tags: c#, authentication, nancy

I need to have Forms Authentication for some modules and Stateless Authentication for others. With Forms Authentication, the login page needs to set a `returnUrl`.

We had this working with application-wide Forms Authentication (enabled for pipelines), but we're stuck trying to enable hybrid authentication.

Per https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2439 we have to enable the forms authentication in the module constructor:

```
public abstract class FormsAuthenticationModuleBase : NancyModule
{
    protected FormsAuthenticationModuleBase(IUserMapper userMapper)
        : this(userMapper, string.Empty)
    {
    }

    protected FormsAuthenticationModuleBase(IUserMapper userMapper, string modulePath)
        : base(modulePath)
    {
        var formsAuthConfiguration = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration
        {
            RequiresSSL = false,
            UserMapper = userMapper,
            RedirectUrl = "/login?returnUrl=" + Context.Request.Headers["X-Original-URL"].FirstOrDefault()
        };

        // Enable calls RequiresAuthentication.
        FormsAuthentication.Enable(this, formsAuthConfiguration);
    }
}
```

The issue is that `Context` is `null` at construction time.

How can we enable Forms Authentication on a per module basis and set a `RedirectUrl` that includes a `returnUrl`?

(See also https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Forms-authentication )

**Update**

On the advice of [@khellang](https://twitter.com/khellang) I tried adding a [before hook](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-before-and-after-module-hooks):

```
Before.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(
    ctx =>
    {
        if (!formsAuthConfiguration.RedirectUrl.Contains("?"))
        {
            formsAuthConfiguration.RedirectUrl +=
                "?returnUrl=" + ctx.Request.Headers["X-Original-URL"].FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return null;
    });
```

(With the original `RedirectUrl = "/login"`)

This results in a 405 that I can't debug into. (Same for the `Before +=` syntax.)

He also suggested moving everything into the hook, rather than storing the configuration and mutating it; that didn't work either.

Currently I'm using [if/else logic in RequestStartup](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/12/20/configuring-multiple-forms-authentication-sections-with-nancyfx/) (as opposed to the above approach). That works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [if/else logic in RequestStartup](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/12/20/configuring-multiple-forms-authentication-sections-with-nancyfx/) works.